# How to start multiple threads when an event occurs?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I am creating a service, which is waiting for a Logon event. When this event occurs, the service should start a thread, which will do the rest of the work.

In the service:

```
while ( WaitForSingleObject( ghSvcStopEvent, 0 ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
{
    DWORD dwEventFlags;
    BOOL bRes;

    // WTSWaitSystemEvent waits until a logon event ocurs
    bRes = WTSWaitSystemEvent( WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_EVENT_LOGON, &dwEventFlags );
    if ( dwEventFlags == WTS_EVENT_NONE )
    {
        ShowErrorText( "Cancelling waiting for logon event. Service shutting down.", 0, true );
    }
    if ( bRes )
    {
        // Someone has logged on
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, &dwThreadID );
    }
    else
    {
        ShowErrorText( "WTSWaitSystemEvent failed.", GetLastError(), true );
    }
}//while
```

My question is, how can I close correctly the handles returned by CreateThread? If I want to use WaitForMultipleObjects then the first parameter is the size of the threads. The maximum number of object handles is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, which is 36. So this means that I can only start 36 threads. But if the service is running a very long time, then it won't be enough, if a user is logging on more than 36 times, without restarting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread pool to avoid needing to destroy threads. When your application exits you do not need to close the handles - Windows will do that for you.

Comment: Do you know where could I find a simple example?